# Multiple results as part of the arguments in a function

Tags: lua

Suppose I have these three functions:

```
function getVector2D()
    return 66.0, 77.0
end
 
function setVector2D(x, y)
    print(x.." "..y)
end

function setVector3D(x, y, z)
    print(x.." "..y.." "..z)
end
```

If I use `setVector2D(getVector2D())`, I have no problems because the multiple-value return from `getVector2D` will be applied to `setVector2D` and the result will be `66.0 77.0`.
But what if I want to partially apply the arguments as in: `setVector3D(getVector2D(), 88.0)`?

The expect (and obtained) result would be only `x` evaluated from `getVector2D`, as [the manual](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html) says:

> `print(foo2(), 1)       -->  a   1`
> `print(foo2() .. "x")   -->  ax         (see below)`
>
> When the call to foo2 appears inside an expression, Lua adjusts the number of results to one; so, in the last line, only the "a" is used in the concatenation.

The question is: is there any way to get the multiple values from `getVector2D` in the call above and expect the result to be `66.0 77.0 88.0` in a clean way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there no such way.

Easest way is use variables `loaval z,x,y = 88.0, getVector2D()`

You can use proxy function:

```
function proxy2D(t, z) return t[1],t[2],z end
setVector3D(proxy2D({getVector2D()}, 88.0))
```

or

```
function proxy2D(z, x, y) return x,y,z end
setVector3D(proxy2D(88.0, getVector2D()))
```

last variant also exists in `vararg` library as `vararg.append` function.

Comment: The `vararg` library you are referring to is not available in plain Lua.

Comment: `vararg` library has 2 implementation Lua and C. This is Lua version https://github.com/moteus/lua-vararg/blob/master/vararg.lua

Comment: Yes, but it isn't a built-in library.

Comment: I see.. the only other option I thought was using the function for the last arguments, e.g. `A(1, B(2, 3))` returns `1, 2, 3` where A and B just return their arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use temporary tables to capture the arguments and append additional ones?

```
function getVector2D()
    return 66.0, 77.0
end

function setVector2D(x, y)
    print(x,y)
end

function setVector3D(x, y, z)
    print(x,y,z)
end

local args = {getVector2D()}
args[#args+1] = 88.0
setVector3D(unpack(args))

>> 66   77  88
```